# mips setting variable questions

Tags: mars-simulator

Write a piece of MIPS code that, given values in $s0 and $s1, put into 
the $t* registers the following:

```
$t0 = $s0
$t1 = $s1
$t2 = $t0 + $t1
$t3 = $t1 + $t2
...
$t7 = $t5 + $t6
```

In other words, for each register from $t2 to $t7, it stores the sum of 
the previous two $t* register values. The $s0 and $s1 registers 
contain the initial values.
Don't set the value of $s0 and $s1 in your code. Instead, learn how to 
set it manually with MARS. Save your code into sum.s.

so i take it just wants me to just go like

```
add $t4, $t2, $t3
add $t5, $t3, $t4
```

etc

but what does it mean to set the value of $s0 and $s0 not in my code, but with MARS?
I realize MARS is an IDE, but how do you set variables with MARS?

One additional quesiton, how do you even set breakpoints in MARS? I can do it with the gui version, but they want us to use the terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting input variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211090/setting-input-variables)

Comment: Please do not duplicate your questions. This is not a hotline helpdesk with instant answers:) People of various skills visit the questions at various times. Questions, even old one, usually are not deleted only because they are not answered. When someone's knowledgeable enough in the subject shows up, (s)he will answer. Sending duplicates only adds trash that someone has to investigate and remove.